# Reference of Hadith "make things easy and not difficult" "يسِّروا ولا تعسِّروا"?

Tags: hadith, reference-request

Please let me know the refrence  of hadith "Give tidings (to the people) ; do not create (in their minds) aversion (towards religion)" "يسِّروا ولا تعسِّروا"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hadith is sahih and appears in both Sahihs and elsewhere several times, with more or less slightly different wordings:

- In Sahih al-Bukhari:
  In the book of knowledge (see [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/3/11)) in the book of Good manners (see [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/78/152))
- In Sahih Muslim:
  in the book of Jihad and expedition  on the authority of abu Musa al-Ash'ari (see [here](https://sunnah.com/muslim/32/6)) and on the authoirty of Anas ibn Malik  (See [here](https://sunnah.com/muslim/32/9))
- In al-Adab al-Mufrad of imam al-Bukhari:
  In the chapter on calming (see [here](https://sunnah.com/adab/26/12)) in the chapter excusing and pardoning people (see [here](https://sunnah.com/adab/12/8))
- And in abu Dawood's Sunan in the book of general behaviour (see [here](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/43/63))
- And in many other hadith collections such as Musnad Ahmad and 'Abdurrazaq's al-Mossanaf etc.

Note that the following version which appears in both Sahih al-Bukhari and Sahih Muslim shows that the statement of the hadith was in first place said to Mu'ad ibn Jabal and abu Musa al-Ash'ari -as it was stated in the Arabic dual plural-:

> "The Prophet (ﷺ) sent Mu`adh and Abu Musa to Yemen telling them.
>   '**Treat the people with ease and don't be hard on them**; give them glad tidings and don't fill them with aversion; and love each other, and don't differ."
>   **يَسِّرَا وَلاَ تُعَسِّرَا**، وَبَشِّرَا وَلاَ تُنَفِّرَا، وَتَطَاوَعَا وَلاَ تَخْتَلِفَا
>   (See for example in [Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/56/244) and [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/32/7))

Note that the above version is also quoted different times in both Sahihs and elsewhere.